# Android Studio - Google Maps API works for debug version but not for release version

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I've built an app that contains a Map from Google Maps API. When I was trying it, and debugging directly from Android Studio, all worked fine  Now I released the app, and in the release version, the map is not displayed anymore, only the location-button is displayed.

Do I need a new google maps api key for the release version in `\app\src\release\res\values\google_maps_api` and if I do so, how do I get the right key?

Or is there another problem with the release version?

Answer (score 1):

You need to Release key for your application :

1. Create your own signing key that you will use for publishing, using Keytool : http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#cert
2. Get the MD5 fingerprint of your newly generated key : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey#getfingerprint
3. Submit the signature to this link to get your Google Maps key : https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup?hl=fr
4. Export your application with your newly created key, in Eclipse : right click on your projet -> Android Tools -> Export signed application package.

Careful to keep your certificate in a safe place, because you will need it if you want to publish an update of your app on Google Play.

Answer (score 0):

If you use App Signing by Google Play(https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423)

You need another API KEY Application restrictions : not from your debug, release keystore, but form Google Play Console -> Release management -> App signing -> App signing certificate -> SHA-1 certificate fingerprint.

Good Luck.